# Last observations not carried forward using fill or na.locf for character variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, zoo

I have a `data.table` generated by fread in which some of the columns contain `NA`s.
I would like to fill the values for these specific columns with the last available data from the previous row ("Last observation carried forward" mechanism).

I've tried `zoo`'s `na.locf` combined with `dplyr`'s `mutate_at` and `tidyr`'s fill function to fill these NAs.

```
library(dplyr) ## needed for mutate_at
library(tidyr) ## needed for fill
library(data.table) ## needed for fread
library(zoo) ## needed for na.locf

tempImport <- fread(test_filename, header = T, check.names = T, drop = "V198") %>% ## read in csv
     mutate_at(vars(VP:frameRate), na.locf)

tempImport <- fread(test_filename, header = T, check.names = T, drop = "V198") %>% ## read in csv
     fill(VP:frameRate)
```

Both of them generally returned without errors and worked for the `int` and `num` variables, but not for the `char` variables (same output of `str` for both options from above).

```
> str(tempImport[1093:1094, 192:197])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ VP             : int  1 1
 $ condition      : int  2 2
 $ date           : chr  "2020_Feb_24_0905" ""
 $ expName        : chr  "Ment_Rot" ""
 $ psychopyVersion: chr  "3.2.4" ""
 $ frameRate      : num  59.9 59.9
```

I know that `data.table`'s `nafill` does not work with `char` variables. Is this also true for `na.locf` and `fill`? I could not find anything in the documentation.
If so: is there a possibility to fill in those `char` variables with previous values? Also: these `NA`s generally **only** occur in these columns in the *last* row. However, as I want to use the code for a batch script, I don't know the index number of the last row for every `fread` output. I would be open to workaround solutions to achieve something comparable to the above solutions.

Comment: I made an attempt you answer your question(s?). You need a reproducible example and be clearer about what your questions are.

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your main question but:

> is there a possibility to fill in those `char` variables with previous values

Yes, there is a *hack*:

```
DT <- data.table(x = c("hi", NA, NA, "ho", NA, "bye"))
DT[, x[nafill(replace(.I, is.na(X), NA), "locf")]]
# [1] "hi"  "hi"  "hi"  "ho"  "ho"  "bye"
```

Regarding:

> don't know the index number of the last row for every fread output

You can use `.N` to select the last row:

```
DT[.N]
fread("file.csv")[.N]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple data.table solution

```
dt <- data.table(v = c("A", "A", NA, "B", NA))
dt[, v:=v[1], by=cumsum(!is.na(v))]
dt
```